# MongoDB Project/Aggregate to get all sub documents latest arrays entries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I use MongoDB for storing time series data with gaps. Each document belongs to one item and holds the changes for several measure points. 
Each measure point has an id, I used the following id scheme `some-id-XXX` in the example below.

The application writes only changes to the specific sub document. Hence there is the possibility of gaps in the series the APP loads the whole document checks it for changes and updates the sub document/s (`"some-id-1"` for example) which has changes.

```
{
    "_id": "XXX-DAY_OF_YEAR",
    "date": null /* A date used for the TTL index */,
    "series" : {
        "some-id-1" : [
            {
                "ts" : 1457959837,
                "value" : 385,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1457959837,
                "value" : 385,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458286255,
                "value" : 380,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458346606,
                "value" : 375,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458381111,
                "value" : 368,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458381461,
                "value" : 365,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458606338,
                "value" : 385,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458606338,
                "expired": true
            }
        ],
        "some-id-2" : [
            {
                "ts" : 1439802083,
                "value" : 430,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            }
        ],
        "some-id-42" : [
            {
                "ts" : 1457545167,
                "value" : 518,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458483441,
                "value" : 1034,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458518979,
                "value" : 518,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            }
        ],
        "some-id-1337" : [
            {
                "ts" : 1458017854,
                "value" : 361,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458050773,
                "value" : 384,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458115173,
                "value" : 383,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458143968,
                "value" : 382,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458176011,
                "value" : 381,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458212600,
                "value" : 384,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458245285,
                "value" : 383,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458277108,
                "value" : 382,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458309875,
                "value" : 379,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458338258,
                "value" : 378,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458374471,
                "value" : 374,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458405856,
                "value" : 364,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458435330,
                "value" : 363,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458471185,
                "value" : 362,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458500103,
                "value" : 361,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458535837,
                "value" : 360,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458568805,
                "value" : 364,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            },
            {
                "ts" : 1458633188,
                "value" : 384,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem with this approcach is the traffic generated by loading whole document, which is needed for checking for changes or gaps.

If I would be able to retrieve only the most recent value (the last value in the array) the traffic would be slashed up.

```
{
    "series" : {
        "some-id-1" : [
            {
                "ts" : 1458606338,
                "expired": true
            }
        ],
        "some-id-2" : [
            {
                "ts" : 1439802083,
                "value" : 430,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            }
        ],
        "some-id-42" : [
            {
                "ts" : 1458518979,
                "value" : 518,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            }
        ],
        "some-id-1337" : [
            {
                "ts" : 1458633188,
                "value" : 384,
                "meta" : "some meta info …"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As long I know the ID I can use a projection to retrieve the last recent entry.

```
db.Series.find( 
{ "series.some-id-42" : { $exists: true } },
{ "series.some-id-42.$": -1}
)
```

But since a change can contain gaps I do not know all ids occurring in the target series document.

Is there any possibility to archive this using the aggregation framework or with some clever projection?

My only idea is storing the recent values in a more compact form and project only `{last_recent: 1}`:

```
{
    "recent": {
        "some-id-1" : 0,
        "some-id-2" : 430,
        "some-id-42" : 518,
        "some-id-1337" : 384
    }
    "series" : { /* … */ }
}
```

But I hope there is a more elegant solution for this problem.

Comment: If you are expecting the `"some-id-x"` part to be "dynamic" then that is just not going to happen with the aggregation framework. It's actually not a very good design either, both in the usage of "named keys" as well as not being very practical to use this for storage of multiple values in this way. This really could to with a redesign as the whole structure does not look like a good idea for the intended usage that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is that you're storing data in the field names, that being the ID.

The schema should probably be:

```
{
    "series": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "content": [
                {
                    "ts": 1458606338,
                    "expired": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "content": [
                {
                    "ts": 1439802083,
                    "value": 430,
                    "meta": "some meta info …"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 42,
            "content": [
                {
                    "ts": 1458518979,
                    "value": 518,
                    "meta": "some meta info …"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1337,
            "content": [
                {
                    "ts": 1458633188,
                    "value": 384,
                    "meta": "some meta info …"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If I would use a scheme where the id is not part of a document field updates could get dangerous.

Currently I am able to push to a specific series:

 db.s.update({_id: /* … */ }, { 
  $push: { "series.1337": {"ts": 123, "val": 12, "m": "…"} } 
 })

When using your suggested scheme I would hav to use the array index for pushes:

 db.s.update({_id: /* … */ }, { 
  $push: { "series.0.content": {"ts": 123, "val": 12, "m": "…"} } 
 })

Comment: This could lead to pushes to the wrong array when multiple new series gets created concurrent with some pushes to already known series.

 db.s.update({_id: /* … */ }, { 
  $push: { "series": {
   "id": 2048,
   "content": [{"ts": 123, "val": 12, "m": "…"}]
  }}
 })

But maybe this risk is so unlikely to give it a try.

Comment: You have a unique id in wach nested document.  This means you can use either `$` or `$elemMatch` in your update to push tothe correct nested document.